# Airflow task run no matter what happen to downstream

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have three task in one dag.

Task A run first. Task B runs if task A is successful.

I have Task C which has run after Task B but it is not depend up Task B or Task A success or failure.

Task C needs to no matter what happen to task A and B. However, it needs to run after task A and B is completed.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have a task run after other tasks are done, but regardless of the outcome of their execution, set the `trigger_rule` parameter to `all_done` like so:

```
my_task = MyOperator(task_id='my_task',
                     trigger_rule='all_done'
```

See the [trigger rule documentation](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules) for more options